# On Click (text box,) Open Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to build a basic front-end to link information together that would be accessible by clicking a text box (or a button) on the front page of the GUI. Basically, I have a number of text boxes for the different "functions" I want to show information on.

How do I make it so that on click, that box will open up a new window that I've already designeD? Within the solution (WPApplication,) I have all of the .xaml's set up (that are the seperate windows) in the solution already- I just want to call the on-click to open them. I figured it'd just be Show('Window Name') after private/as/handles, but it gives me an expression. Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub PO_info_MouseDown(Sendar As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles PO_Info.Mousedown
    Show('PO Information') 
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have to declare the Window object before you can Show it.

Comment: this isn't C#, please update to visualbasic

Comment: Wait...since when does Show() has a String argument? - It doesn't. If your Windows object you want to show is stored in a "myWin" variable for example, you would do `myWin.Show()`.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out my comment, the new window objects that you created are classes, you need to create an instance of the class before the Show Method will work. Lets assume that your PO Information forms class is POInfo you would need to do something like this.

```
POInfo POInformation = new POInfo;
POinformation.Show();  //This is where your show method is
```

Since your code looks like vb.net it would look like this in VB

```
Dim POInformation as New PoInfo
POInformation.Show()
```